# jQuery show content based on dropdown

Tags: jquery

I wish to show content based on dropdown value. So 2005 select will only show content with date of 2005 etc.

HTML:

```
    <select id="year" name="Year"> 
        <option value="#" selected="selected">Year...</option> 
        <option value="#">2007</option> 
        <option value="#">2006</option> 
        <option value="#">2005</option> 
    </select>
```

-

```
<li class="pr">
   <a class="image" href="image.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></a>
   <span class="date">2006</span>
</li>

<li class="pr">
   <a class="image" href="image.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></a>
   <span class="date">2007</span>
</li>
```

Had a look at this:
[jQuery dropdown hide show div based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019096/jquery-dropdown-hide-show-div-based-on-value)

but seems overkill?

Comment: I don't think the one you linked is overkill, it's rather simple. You can simplify the hideAllDivs() method a bit since you're using classes and don't need to list out each individual id to hide.

Comment: the list of dates is variable though and could be 20 or so long, the linked method would mean writing a huge list.

Comment: Not at all. Hide ALL $(".pr") and then show the parent of $("span.date") where the value matches the selected option (one of the answers below already states how to do this). The concept is the same as the question you linked, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('select#year').change(function(){

    theVal = $(this).children(':selected').text();
    $('span.date').each(function(){

        if($(this).text()==theVal){
            $('li.pr').hide();
            $(this).parent().show();
        }
    });
});
```

Sorry, this one should work with the HTML you have, old one was based of value.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do this, one of which is

```
<select id="year" name="Year"> 
            <option value="#" selected="selected">Year...</option> 
            <option value="2007">2007</option> 
            <option value="2006">2006</option> 
            <option value="2005">2005</option> 
</select>
```

Put id's on your li's

```
<li class="pr" id="2006">
   <a class="image" href="image.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></a>
   <span class="date">2006</span>
</li>

<li class="pr" id="2007">
   <a class="image" href="image.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></a>
   <span class="date">2007</span>
</li>
```

The jquery

```
$(function() {
    $('ul li').hide();  
    $('#year').change(function() {
       var year = $(this).val(); 
       $('#'+ year).show();  
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some quick JS, tested on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ehihuc), [source](http://jsbin.com/ehihuc/2/edit)

```
$('#year').live('change', function(){
  var Year = $(this).val();
  $('li.pr').hide();
  $('span.date').each(function(){
    if ($(this).text() == Year){
      $(this).parent().show();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

But you will need to change your html a bit for this to work:

```
<option value="#" selected="selected">Year...</option> 
<option>2007</option> 
<option>2006</option> 
<option>2005</option>
```