# How to get the page based on the selection in a drop down list in Django

Tags: python, django, drop-down-menu, django-models, django-forms

I'm a new on Django. One question confused me about the drop down list in Django. I'd like to know how to change the content in a page based on the selection in the drop down list in Django.

In **Model.py** I design the fields as:

```
STATUS_IN_CHOICE = (
    ('Pending','Pending'),
    ('Passed','Passed'),
    ('Failed','Failed'),
)
Status = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=STATUS_IN_CHOICE,
                          default='Pending')
```

The respected result I want is, if I select "Passed" in the drop down list. All the passed cases show in the page. Others are the same.

I have no idea how to code the template and connect with the field now. Cause in my opinion, it's not a forms (post) at all.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that involves back-end processing? Or are you looking for a client-side-only solution (meaning all cases provided to the client-side and the filtering is done there)?

Comment: Only client-side-only, back-end processing I can filter out in view.py based on the drop down value selection

Answer (score 1):

You have basically two alternatives, and both of involve the use of javascript.

You either:

- need to preload all content at the initial page render, if the content is small and simple, and then [use javascript on the drop-down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272295/jquery-show-content-based-on-dropdown) to display the appropriate parts of it.
- or to fetch the content [with ajax requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28341345/940098) depending on the value of the drop-down and render it when it loads.

Neither of the above the use of a model if the drop-down is for display filter only, and no storing is required. You could achieve the same with a simple django form or plain HTML.