# jquery show/hid div based on drop down

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide

i'm trying to show/hid various divs based on a user input from a select drop down box.  actually, to begin with, i'm trying to directly implement the code shown in [jQuery dropdown hide show div based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019096/jquery-dropdown-hide-show-div-based-on-value), however i'm missing something simple which prevents it from working at http://www.intertwineimages.com/form2.html  here is my complete code, can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript">
hideAllDivs = function () {
    $("#hourly").hide();
    $("#per_diem").hide();
    $("#fixed").hide();
};

handleNewSelection = function () {

    hideAllDivs();

    switch ($(this).val()) {
        case '1':
            $("#hourly").show();
        break;
        case '2':
            $("#per_diem").show();
        break;
        case '3':
            $("#fixed").show();
        break;
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#project_billing_code_id").change(handleNewSelection);

    // Run the event handler once now to ensure everything is as it should be
    handleNewSelection.apply($("#project_billing_code_id"));

});
</script>
<select id="project_billing_code_id">
    <option value="">Pick one</option>
    <option value="1">1-Hourly</option>
    <option value="2">2-Per Diem</option>
    <option value="3">3-Fixed</option>
</select>

<div id="hourly">Hourly</div>
<div id="per_diem">Per Diem</div>
<div id="fixed">Fixed</div>

</html>
```

**EDIT: corrected code**

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
hideAllDivs = function () {
    $("#hourly").hide();
    $("#per_diem").hide();
    $("#fixed").hide();
};

handleNewSelection = function () {

    hideAllDivs();

    switch ($(this).val()) {
        case '1':
            $("#hourly").show();
        break;
        case '2':
            $("#per_diem").show();
        break;
        case '3':
            $("#fixed").show();
        break;
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#project_billing_code_id").change(handleNewSelection);

    // Run the event handler once now to ensure everything is as it should be
    handleNewSelection.apply($("#project_billing_code_id"));

});
</script>
<select id="project_billing_code_id">
    <option value="">Pick one</option>
    <option value="1">1-Hourly</option>
    <option value="2">2-Per Diem</option>
    <option value="3">3-Fixed</option>
</select>

<div id="hourly">Hourly</div>
<div id="per_diem">Per Diem</div>
<div id="fixed">Fixed</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Well it seems to work. Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/qzSu6/. BTW have you included the jquery js file ?

Comment: Right, it does work on jsfiddle, but I can't get it to work on my server (http://www.intertwineimages.com/form2.html), wondering why it wont.

Comment: My advice to you is to completely ditch jQuery and learn how to use real JavaScript.

Comment: include jquery. its not setup

Comment: You are missing the reference to jquery.

Comment: Seconded, your example works fine http://jsfiddle.net/VVZGM/, you mustn't be including jquery file as said... or maybe you have a browser extension that's causing it to fail? Have you tried debug mode (F12 in IE, CTRL+SHIFT+J in Chrome) to see what script errors you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you have not included the jquery file for http://www.intertwineimages.com/form2.html

Comment: ah! that's the simple thing i was missing.  could you show me how exactly to do this or elucidate on this issue?

Comment: Its pretty simple. I have firebug installed on my firefox. When I opened the url I got an error in firebug saying `$ is not defined`.

Comment: great thanks, got it!  original post has been modified to show correct answer for those interested.